# Problem with menu in Polylang / WordPress (Twenty-twenty-three theme)

Tags: polylang

I've set up all translations and menu after Polylang install.
In site theme editor I see correct menu (including pages from menu and language switch), but on front-end I see just list of pages (incl. 404 and without sub menus and language switcher).

There is idea that Polylang can't see menu area and shows page list instead by default.
Is here any body who has any ideas how to beat this?)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To use Polylang language switcher with TT2 and TT3, you need to install the [Site Editor Classic Features](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fse-classic/) plugin first.

Then you can add a block named Widget Classic and select the legacy Navigation Menu.